# Quiz script in from json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm making a quiz script to learn javascript.
I have a json file that have question and answers for quiz

example:

```
"quiz": [
{
  id:"0";
  question: "Who is the strongest?",
  answers: [
   {"name":"btn1","next_question":"1"},
   {"name":"btn2","next_question":"2"},]
   },
 },
{
  id:"1";
  question: "What is the best site ever created?",
  answers: [{
    {"name":"btn1","next_question":"0"},
    {"name":"btn2","next_question":"2"},]
  },
},
{
  id:"2";
  question: "Where is Waldo really?",
  answers: {
    {"name":"btn1","next_question":"1"},
    {"name":"btn2","next_question":"2"},
  },
}];}
```

So I need to make always quiz start from the question with id (0).
The field next_question shows what the next question will be.
How I can make this possible? Can anyone please help me with this?

Kinda similar quiz (https://github.com/evgeniikucheriavii/JS-quizes)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I would start at [mcve]

Comment: There are a lot of missing details that render your question vague and not getting a response. You gave us an example of data but the code is missing and therefore it is not possible to give you an answer. How do you show a question? What do you do when a question is answered? Will you navigate to the next question url? (how is it calculated?) Do an ajax request and load the result in a div?  You will need to give us more details on what is going on to have a chance to be helped, and sometime doing this you will find the solution by yourself too. Please add some more info.